# i have ddeleted Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org folder to update the flutter packages but showing error in flutter packages get

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I tried to delete the flutter packages for the project and update the same with following commands
but couldn't find the solution why this packages get is finding the file "pubspec.yaml" in "\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_admob-0.9.3+2" folder. here is the error. can anyone tell how to update the packages from my project's pubspec.yaml" file

```
PS D:\flutter\delimeals> flutter packages get
Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "C:\Users\omkar\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_admob-0.9.3+2".
Running "flutter pub get" in delimeals...
pub get failed (66; Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in
"C:\Users\omkar\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_admob-0.9.3+2".)
```

I am getting this error after I deleted the pub folder as wanted to delete unwanted packages.

```
PS D:\flutter\delimeals> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1282], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.17.3 at D:\flutter\flutter
    • Framework revision b041144f83 (2 weeks ago), 2020-06-04 09:26:11 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\omkar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\omkar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\omkar\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.11.0
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this,

- Run this command `flutter pub cache repair`
- `flutter clean` (from project directory)
- try to run again